# Bluetooth connection between Ubuntu and Android

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

Since I bought my laptop within installed Ubuntu software, several years ago, still I cannot make bluetooth connection between my mobile smartphone Sony Xperia (Android) and the laptop (Ubuntu).
  I have installed Bluetooth/ Bluetooth manager from Ubuntu software on the laptop and several bluetooth applications on the smartphone but until today have no results. Simply, the Ubuntu and the Android do not recognize or pair at all. On the other side I can make bluetooth connection between two mobile phones, but no connection with Ubuntu.
  I am asking for any solution, like Bluetooth adapter,  but before I order it online I would like to know will it work or not? Will bluetooth adapter establish a connection between my laptop and smartphone?
  Here are some details considering my question. I have Laptop brand Dell inspirion 15, 3000 series, ram 3,8 GiB, processor Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4, OS - Ubuntu 16,04 LTS 64 bit, graphic – Intel.
 The purpose of my question is to find proper answer about bluetooth connection, I would use it to transfer pictures or any files from my smart phone to laptop or in opposite direction. Do you have any idea how to make the bloutooth functional on Ubuntu 16,04?

Comment: First of all what's your intended use of said Bluetooth connection? Please [edit] your question for clarification and also post details about the hardware specifications.

Comment: Thank you Gabriela for your answer, here are some details considering my question. 
I have Laptop brand Dell inspirion 15, 3000 series, 
ram 3,8 GiB, 
processor Intel® Core™ i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4, 
OS - Ubuntu 16,04 LTS 64 bit, 
graphic – Intel

The purpose of my question is to find proper answer about bluetooth connection, I would use it to transfer pictures or any files from my smart phone to laptop or in opposite direction. Do you have any idea how to make the bloutooth functional on Ubuntu 16,04?

Comment: I would appreciate if somebody would send me complete commands to copy and paste into the Terminal. In order to make bluetooth connection between android and ubuntu OS. For Ubuntu 16. version. Thanks.